# g2p-seq2seq-cmudict model not found

Tags: tensorflow, cmusphinx

I am attempting to run the g2p-seq2seq tool in the interest of adding words to a dictionary for cmusphinx.

I am following the instructions on [the g2p github page](https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq).

I have installed TensorFlow using the virtualenv method as specified on the tensorflow install page.

I am in the virtualenv environment using `$ source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate` as per specified on the tensorflow page.

But when I attempt to run the command:
`g2p-seq2seq --interactive --model g2p-seq2seq-cmudict`

I receive `RuntimeError: Model not found in g2p-seq2seq-cmudict`

But I have the "g2p-seq2seq-cmudict" folder downloaded from the link on the github page and it is in the "Documents" folder where I am running the command from.

And lastly here is a picture for further understanding [screenie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJfo4.png)

Comment: We temporary broke it with upgrade to tensorflow 1.0. We will upload an updated model soon. tracked at https://github.com/cmusphinx/g2p-seq2seq/issues/65

Comment: Oh alright, thanks. I was so confused.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev If possible do you think you could post an answer to this question when the new dictionary is finished? If your too busy I understand.

Comment: Yes, sure, it's running, just requires a lot of computational resources so a bit slow.

Comment: updated the model, download https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/G2P%20Models/g2p-seq2seq-cmudict.tar.gz/download

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev Thank you very much Mr. Shmyrev!

Answer (score 0):

first you sould to determine the file of your dictionary will you build,

example in

cd /home/cmudict-master/ pick your dictionary file -> cmudict.dict

then you sould have some folder to include the model will be created after g2p training your dictionary

example in 
/home/cmudict-master/english-model

for that example the command will be right here

g2p-seq2seq --train cmudict.dict --model english-model

hope it will done

Comment: I appreciate the effort Mr. Qaulan but in the comments of the question you will find the developer of this software has said that the current dictionary was broken in the latest update to tensorflow, there aware of the issue and (I assume anyways) that their working to fix it.

Comment: The answer is valid though, a model can be trained